# Copying and pasting Bootstrap [3.3.7] code for navbar [or basically anything] not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I've been trying to code my first small website and run into an issue. I've been trying to manually code a navbar but Bootstrap seemed a better and quicker solution, though copying and pasting is not working for me. jQuery first seems to be a common issue but I have that and it still does not work. I don't really have a clue to what I am doing wrong though my knowledge is limited at this point.
Full code and output image + desired look for navbar below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </nav>
      </body>
    </html>
```

My output in Chrome 60.0.3112.90: [http://imgur.com/OV98vwI](https://imgur.com/OV98vwI)
Desired output for navbar: [http://imgur.com/7nyb2hc](https://imgur.com/7nyb2hc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Bootstrap v4 not v3, `btn-outline-success` and `my-2 my-sm-0` those are added in Bootstrap v4 so go here and checkout their example/docs https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Though this seems to be bootstrap v4 which according to their website "Dropped IE8, IE9, and iOS 6 support. v4 is now only IE10+ and iOS 7+. For sites needing either of those, use v3." Since I'd like more compatibility, I'd like to keep v3. Since v4 is in alpha I believe all code on their website should work with v4, no? How can I use this with v3?

Comment: @JoãoRamos `btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0` those are v4 only so yeah, it is BS v4

Comment: @Ashishsah 's solution worked perfectly though I'm not quite following how. Is there a simple way to see if something is v4-specific so I can understand what will work and what won't when I copy it? As in, search for a navbar compatible with v3 out of the box.

Comment: @JoãoRamos he just copied the v3 example to you, of course, it will work. The code you posted it is v4

Comment: I think I mixed up the downloads of bootstrap v4 and v3. Seems like I have wasted your time. Sorry about that but thanks for the help. It put an end to 1h of lost time. Should/Can I delete this post?

Comment: @JoãoRamos this `outline` style `btn-outline-success` is new to v4, if you see this it is v4, also something like `my-2 my-sm-0` and `my-2 my-lg-0` are v4

Comment: @JoãoRamos it's ok, mark the correct answer, in case others might have the same issue =D

Answer (score 0):

you need to link CSS file first and after that your js file. First link CSS after that jQuery and then your bootstrap js file.

```
 <link         href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: try that and let me know, There can be any other problem too...But while linking files we link the CSS first after that JS

Comment: hey have a look over this as you want a navbar so :

Comment: Your solution works perfectly! Did you basically convert from v4 to v3 of bootstrap? I can see you changed quite a lot of code but I don't really understand why this works now.

Comment: because you were using the old format...its not supported in the latest version...I think so....you can have a look at getbootstrap.com documentation and try using jsbin(its just a suggestion as you are new)...

Comment: Just go with the documentation and link it correctly everything will be alright...

Comment: According to @DanielH , seems like what I was using was v4 i.e. the new format. Weird that's in alpha mode and already they have it set as default for their components code on their website. I literally copy and pasted the whole thing from their website. I have no clue how to tell v3 from v4 apart looking at the code...

Comment: I think I mixed up the downloads of bootstrap v4 and v3. Seems like I have wasted your time. Sorry about that but thanks for the help. It put an end to 1h of lost time.

Comment: you can see my code I just linked everything correctly and CSS first after that and then I too went and copied the code...here they ans in a very good manner and it's too good, so it often crosses our mind. Just go with documentation and if it helped you upvote my ans

Comment: Just did it. Thanks.